# Linkedin oAuth login failure with error "Your LinkedIn Network Will Be Back Soon"

Tags: linkedin-api

[Here's a link to the screen recording of the issue.] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vebV3izUTfP1o7NyXUP9irPM_oc89phi/view?usp=sharing).

The problem is not, in general, with accessing or logging into LinkedIn. I'm working on an app that uses the LinkedIn OAuth client to allow users to add their LinkedIn accounts.

My app https://notionsocial.web.app/ redirects the user to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=77hkxxkjkqzq2n&redirect_uri=https://notionsocial.web.app/auth/callback/linkedin&state=state&scope=r_basicprofile%20w_member_social%20rw_organization_admin%20w_organization_social%20r_organization_social, It opens the LinkedIn authentication screen and was working fine a few days ago.
But now, when a user enters his credentials and clicks "sign in," it does not redirect to my website, with or without an error message. But show this page.
[image]

It is not related to my LinkedIn personal account; I have tried with different accounts and different browsers. Even a user of my app has encountered this issue on his computer
I have even tried other social scheduling websites and logged on to them using LinkedIn successfully.
But when I tried creating a new LinkedIn developer app and went to the access URL with the new client ID, the same issue occurred.

---

### ✅ UPDATE:

I got in touch with [Linkedin Developer Support](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us), They acknowledged that it was a bug in Linkedin Platform and fixed it in 3-4 days.

Comment: I am also getting this error any idea how to fit it

Comment: @AshishKarpe The problem was fixed, I contacted to LinkedIn and they accepted that it was a bug and fixed it, You should open a developer support ticket, It took them 3-4 days to fix this.